# What does "would" mean in this case?

Tags: modal-verbs, irrealis-mood

Here is the piece from one of the books from the video game The Elder Scrolls IV: Oblivion:

> However, a guild is different than a band. A guild implies an organization with membership rolls. It **would** have a financial structure, which **would** include member dues or some other means of securing funds. It **would** have rules of conduct or behavior.

What does "would" mean in this case? According to the official Russian translation, it appears to be something like "must".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the fragment talks about a hypothetical guild (not a specific one), it uses subjunctive to show the hypothetical characteristics.  "Must" is a stronger verb suggesting some kind of higher order, duty of sorts.  "Would" indicates a suggestion, a supposition about something that doesn't exist in reality.

Answer (score 1):

*Would* is used to express verbs that have a conditional meaning.  While conditional statements often have signal words like *if*, *then*, *when*, etc. this isn't always the case.

*Would have*, *would include*, *would have* all express an action that would exist only if "a guild implies an organization with membership rolls" is true.

*Must* works here and can be considered a "stronger" version of *would*.

If *X is Y because anything Y must be A, B, C* - then Y is not X if A, B, C are not true.

If *X is Y because anything Y would be A, B, C* - well, we are leaving open the possibility that X could still be Y because of some other reason if A, B, or C aren't true.